# How to extract word embedding vectors from a trained Spacy model

Tags: python, spacy

Say for a trained model `XX`, we can use

```
nlp = spacy.load('XX')
len(nlp.vocab.vectors.keys()) #return 0
```

So I think I must missed something here. Is that possible to extract the whole `word:vector` table from the trained model?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to suggest that your model doesn't have any vectors. Using your code snippet, I got 0 with `en_core_web_sm` (English model with no vectors). If used with `en_core_web_lg`, `len(nlp.vocab.vectors.keys()) = 684830`.

To answer your question about word/vector pairs - a simple example you could build on top would be

```
import spacy
language_model = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

word_vectors = dict()
for key, vector in language_model.vocab.vectors.items():
    try:
        word_string = language_model.vocab.strings[key]
        word_vectors[word_string] = vector

    except KeyError:
        continue
```